# How can I multiply a random TensorFlow tensor with a scalar?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing:

```
    with sess.as_default():
        inputs = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=[10],
            minval=-1,
            maxval=1,
            dtype=tf.dtypes.float32
        )

        outputs = inputs * 2
        return inputs, outputs
```

However, this gives me values that are not right:

```
[-0.35871983  0.38419914  0.4842844   0.73863363  0.9198251   0.872777
 -0.02426648 -0.23505187  0.12343764  0.98620296]

[-1.5875583  -0.20895815 -0.38869858 -0.22130203  0.00478601  0.06755686
 -1.2828503   0.13379574  0.91710424  1.2863417 ]
```

The second tensor should be 2x the first one.

I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.0 if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not runnable in its current form. It looks like you gave part of a function, but not the `def` statement. In any case, here is a working example in 1.15.0

```py
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[10],
    minval=-1,
    maxval=1,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float32
)

outputs = inputs * 2

with tf.Session() as s:
    out = s.run([inputs, outputs])
```

And a result for `out` is

```
[array([ 0.39246178,  0.77169394,  0.05202556,  0.979944  , -0.9819634 ,
        -0.56705594,  0.64549136,  0.59383535, -0.5887065 ,  0.90850115],
       dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.78492355,  1.5433879 ,  0.10405111,  1.959888  , -1.9639268 ,
        -1.1341119 ,  1.2909827 ,  1.1876707 , -1.177413  ,  1.8170023 ],
       dtype=float32)]
```

---

The tensorflow 2.x way:

Which version of tensorflow are you using? With tensorflow 2.1.0, the result is doubled. Though I am not using sessions explicitly (tensorflow 2.x does away with that).

```
import tensorflow as tf

def func():
    inputs = tf.random.uniform(
        shape=[10],
        minval=-1,
        maxval=1,
        dtype=tf.dtypes.float32
    )
    outputs = inputs * 2
    return inputs, outputs

func()
```

And the output is

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([-0.02820992,  0.50165296, -0.8978882 ,  0.28159666,  0.00776339,
         0.8920951 ,  0.89258003, -0.25228214, -0.25257993, -0.32589626],
       dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([-0.05641985,  1.0033059 , -1.7957764 ,  0.5631933 ,  0.01552677,
         1.7841902 ,  1.7851601 , -0.5045643 , -0.50515985, -0.6517925 ],
       dtype=float32)>)
```